# C++ to C#: What is equivalent of array of byte pointer with 3 element

Tags: c#, c++, pinvoke, dllimport

I have this code in C++

```
BYTE * apData[3]
```

How to convert it to C# ? ( I'm using DllImport )

Comment: You're using DllImport - how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `byte[]`:

```
[DllImport EntryPoint="myfunc"]
public extern static void MyFunc(byte[]);

byte[] apData = new byte[3];
MyFunc(apData);
```

Comment: The argument in the question seems to be an array of pointers to `BYTE`, not an array of `BYTE`s.

Comment: For what it's worth (it targets C, not C++, but I don't think it makes a difference here), [cdecl](http://cdecl.org/) translates `unsigned char * apData[3]` into `declare apData as array 3 of pointer to unsigned char`. Definitely looks like an array of pointers to byte, not a pointer to an array of bytes.

Comment: If in a 32-bit C++ program you declare `byte* apData[3]` and then check `sizeof(apData)` you will get 12, because it is an array of 3 byte pointers, not an array of 3 bytes.

Comment: You are both correct - I was misreading it as an _assignment_.

Comment: For the benefit of future readers, this answer, whilst currently accepted, is quite clearly wrong as discussed by the commentors above.

Answer (score 1):

That is an array of length 3, of pointer to `BYTE`.

Under the assumption that this appears in a struct it is declared like this:

```
[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst=3)]
IntPtr[] apData;
```

Alternatively, if the array is passed as a parameter, declare that parameter like this:

```
[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray, SizeConst=3)]
IntPtr[] apData
```

Answer (score 0):

just use DLLImport as shown below

```
[DllImport EntryPoint="func"]
public extern static void Func(byte[]);
byte[] apData = new byte[3];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a raw pointer

```
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImportAttribute("<Unknown>", EntryPoint="fun")]
public static extern void fun(System.IntPtr byte_array) ;
```